# Convert ASCII Byte Char array to Hex Byte Array

Tags: c++, hex

I want to convert a ASCII Byte array to Hex Byte Array in C++.
e.g ASCII characters

```
Byte source[3] = {0xB1,0x8E,0x9C};
```

to hex

```
Byte destination[6] = {0x42,0x31,0x38,0x45,0x39,0x43}
```

by mapping from ASCII char to Hex values

> B = 42, 1 = 31, 8 = 38, E = 45, 9 = 39, C = 43

Comment: I have not understood what you are trying to do.:)

Comment: Please add an actual question to your post

Comment: Have you tried to do this on your own?

Comment: Use stringstream and std::hex

Comment: @stark - How would `stringstream` help? OP wants the values in a `BYTE` array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - As OP has 'accepted', then you can now understand what was wanted. Not saying my answer is the best possible, but it's quick, half-decent, and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple lookup table:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char Byte;

int main() {
    char digits[16] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    Byte source[3] = { 0xB1,0x8E,0x9C };
    Byte destination[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        destination[i * 2] = digits[source[i] >> 4]; // High nibble
        destination[i * 2 + 1] = digits[source[i] & 0xF]; // Low nibble
    }
    for (int p = 0; p < 6; ++p) printf(" 0x%02X", destination[p]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: You could make the code a bit more succinct, using:

```
const char *digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

But, as many here on SO have pointed out, short code isn't always the best, or clearest. In this case, the compiler will probably generate pretty much the same machine code.